# Resources for Grails Best Practices

Tags: grails, groovy

This question is too general for answers directly in stackoverflow (see [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226759/best-practices-to-be-followed-while-developing-grails-application)) however I think the community would beneift from having starting points for high quality external articles which can dive into the topic in more detail.

I'd like to see the most informative article on Grails 'Best Practices' based on the following criteria:

- how to split tasks between controllers/views/services/domain objects
- testing
- security
- when to use plugins
- database design considerations
- topics specific to Groovy or Grails that would not be part of general best practice guides

**Please answer with a link to an external article adding just a short summary. Please do NOT comment too much** on whether you think individual ideas/patterns are good otherwise this question will be closed for 'soliciting debate and discussions'

Comment: While I think this question is valuable, it isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow, since there can't (based on the current question) be a single best answer.

Answer (score 3):

This [**InfoQ article on Grails best practices**](http://www.infoq.com/articles/grails-best-practices) has an excellent list of how to split logic between controllers/views/services/domain, testing, config and other Grails specific considerations.

It's a short article and I'd recommend it to any Grails developer

Answer (score 1):

The GrailsPodcast website just had a good 'best practice' session: http://www.grailspodcast.com/blog/id/249 (currently offline)

Comment: It's episode 127 and also available from here http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/grailspodcast.com-groovy-grails/id177436087 while the main site is down

Answer (score 1):

There is a presentation by grails persistence expert Burt Beckwith explaining potential performance issues with out-of-the-box usage of hasMany/belongsTo mappings in GORM:

http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/files/169/gorm%20grails%20meetup%20presentation.pdf

Here's an example of how to apply one of the cases that Burt exposes:

https://mrpaulwoods.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/implementing-burt-beckwiths-gorm-performance-no-collections/